# Kivy on_release: delay or wait feature in .kv file?

Tags: kivy

Is there a way to delay the on_release: action in the .kv file

Code:

```
on_press: inpexpr.source = root.calculate(entry.text)
on_release: outpexpr.source = root.displ(entry.text)
on_release: root.clear()
```

I wish to delay root.clear()

For example

```
on_press: inpexpr.source = root.calculate(entry.text)
on_release: outpexpr.source = root.displ(entry.text)
on_release: wait x seconds -> root.clear()
```

This is ideally so that it gives the the previous on_release: calling the displ() method, time to complete as root.clear() depends on the creation of a file in the displ() method, in order to delete the file. It appears that on_release: root.clear() is being executed too quickly.

How could a time delay be implemented here?

Comment: On second thoughts, im currently trying  to call another method from the kv file , inside the method there will be a kivy.Clock time delay, and then calling the clear() method from that after x amount of time. Still, if there is any way to do it actually inside the .kv file then let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Clock`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html) to set an event dispatched only once, or even interval e.g. every 5 seconds call `root.ping()`.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
Builder.load_string('''
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock
<Test>:
    Button:
        on_release: Clock.schedule_once(root.ping, 3)
    Button:
        on_release: Clock.schedule_interval(root.ping, 5)
''')
class Test(BoxLayout):
    def ping(self, args):
        print('ping', args)
runTouchApp(Test())
```

Comment: Whenever I pass a Method inside schedule_once() it says method() take one argument but two were given